# How do I remove deprecated objects on Android-Studio?

Tags: java, android, oop, android-studio

I'm currently making this app for practice & I came across this weird issue where my objects are crossed out (sort of like how somebody grabs a pencil & marks it wrong on a test) & other minor problems which I don't think is that drastic.  I've included my java class as well as the gradle file because I'm assuming it has something to do with this.

I've tried, with no luck:

1. Build > Clean Project
2. Build > Rebuild Project
3. File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart

[JSONParser.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62vPq.png)

[Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o1md.png)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on cancelled line and on the options select "Go To" and then "Declarations".
In the declared file right click the line number of the annotated class and click "Deannotate".

Answer (score 0):

No no. All your steps won't fix the *warning*. It's a warning about that the class and method is deprecated and should not be used, because there is a newer/better way. If you press `Ctrl + Q` on the warning it should bring up the Javadoc and specify why it's deprecated.

To fix it, you have to avoid using the deprecated method.

Comment: what about the case where the op is supporting a version of android that doesn't have the not-deprecated-method ?

Comment: I pressing `CTRL + Q` on the warning but nothing happens.

Comment: @nanoSecond24 You have to click on the object and press it afterwards. Is there a particular reason why you want to use the apache httpclient? The [URLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) could achieve the same

Comment: I'm following a tutorial in a book I recently purchased.  When you say use URLConnection (I clicked on the link), do you mean `java.net.HttpURLConnection`
 ?  What should I replace this line with?

Comment: @nanoSecond24 You can follow the examples on the dev guide and if you have still questions you can open another post.

Comment: Gothcha.  Thanks, Murat.